# Official IRC channel for stackapps?

Tags: discussion

Since this site exists to support people working on Stack Exchange applications, it would be nice if an 'official' IRC channel existed that people could visit to get help, discuss their applications, design ideas, language implementations etc.

I realize that the purpose *of* this site is to provide help to people using the SE API, however, it does not really facilitate brain storming that could be provided by IRC. Very useful 'side bar' conversations aren't really appropriate here. It can also help make the authors of various API implementations (php / c/c++ / etc) more accessible should they choose to be.

Can an official #stackapps be registered on freenode?

Comment: sounds like we might need a [web-based IRC](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/48249/web-based-irc-for-the-trilogy)

Comment: @Kyle Cronin - That would be nice, perhaps in six to eight weeks :) I plan on collaborating with a few people already working on apps about to go out in the wild tonight / this weekend

Comment: Go for it. I'll try to be there this weekend.

Comment: cgi:irc for web based IRC access is pretty nifty :)

Answer (score 2):

There is now the [official SO web based chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) where you could create room for stackapps. Actually there already is [such a room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27/stack-apps).

Answer (score 1):

Okay, #stackapps is open for business on Freenode.

Feel free to drop by.

Comment: Channel is Empty!

Comment: @Kev: Well I can't be on it 24/7! Seriously, though. The idea is that when many people join it, there will always be *someone* online. I am on usually a lot on the weekends.